# Simple directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to create a directive for my header but it does not seem to work. I have the following:

```
.directive("headerStandard", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "test"
    };
    })
```

This is within an angular module called myApp.directives which also contains other pre-installed directives from a template, which do work.

And in my index.html page (which also references the correct address of the JS file directives) I try:

```
<headerStandard></headerStandard>
```

Can it be more simpeler than this? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the markup from:

```
<headerStandard></headerStandard>
```

to

```
<header-standard></header-standard>
```

This is because Angular's HTML Compiler normalizes the directive's name from camel case form to dash-delimited form (tag name or attribute), read more about it in the [**developer's guide**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives).

Answer (score 1):

The actual name of directive converts to Camel case form in directive() function

Second Word of Directive with capital first letter becomes small proceeding with a hyphen,So on all next Capital first letters will become small and will be preceded with hyphen like yourCustomDirective becomes your-custom-directive

here,headerStandard becomes header-standard in view

so in view you need to use it as

```
<header-standard></header-standard>
```